# Regular expressions with precomposed/decomposed matching

Tags: c++, c, regex, pcre, icu

A human would consider the following strings to represent identical text:

```
>>> [b'a\xc3\xa9b'.decode('utf-8'), b'ae\xcc\x81b'.decode('utf-8')]
['aéb', 'aéb']
```

One string uses precomposed characters, and the other uses decomposed characters, but the resulting text is the same.

However, ICU doesn't seem to support matching precomposed and decomposed characters:

```
UParseError pe;
UErrorCode status;
URegularExpression *regexp = uregex_open(L"a\u0065\u0301b", 4, URegexpFlag::UREGEX_CASE_INSENSITIVE, &pe, &status);
uregex_setText(regexp, L"a\u00E9b", 3, &status);
UBool success = uregex_matches(regexp, 0, &status);  // fails
uregex_close(regexp);
```

Neither does PCRE:

```
$ LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 pcretest <(printf '%s\n' $'/ae\xcc\x81b/i' $'a\xc3\xa9b')
PCRE version 8.45 2021-06-15

/aéb/
aéb
No match
```

So, if I want to handle such cases for arbitrary regexes (so that the results make sense to a human)... then how do I do that?

Is there a way to make existing libraries work correctly for arbitrary Unicode regexes & corpora?

Does there exist **any** regex library that can fully handle Unicode (in addition to full case folding, etc.)?

Ideally I'm hoping for something I can readily use in C++, but solutions in other languages are welcome.

Comment: Just normalize all your strings into the same form first?

Comment: Though if you just want to compare for equivalence and not use any RE matching features, ICU4C has [`unorm_compare()`](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu-docs/apidoc/released/icu4c/unorm2_8h.html#aee41897bd6c4ff7dc7a8db6d37efdcbd)

Comment: @Shawn: "Just normalize" isn't so easy for arbitrary regexes. (What should e.g. the pattern `[ne](◌̃|◌́)` normalize to?)

Comment: Pick NKD or NKC, make sure all your strings are in one. Probably NKD if you're trying to break up grapheme clusters and match individual codepoints of them.

Comment: @Shawn: I think you're misunderstanding where the difficulty is here. The problem isn't picking a normalization (I can pick NKD if you want). The problem is it's actually **performing** the normalization on a *regex*. A regex is not a mere string you can trivially normalize. Again, consider an arbitrary regex like this: [ñ-ẞ][2-◌̀]. How am I supposed to normalize that?! Do you know what that should normalize to for NKD (or NKC, or anything else)?

Comment: That RE... makes no sense. What are you trying to match?

Comment: @Shawn: I don't pick the RE, I receive it as user input. It could be anything. With that particular example, if the user provides that RE, it's presumably meant to be the set of all 2-code-point strings that are equivalent to the Cartesian product of all the code points in the respective charsets. It's well defined, just strange. And even with less strange ones, do notice that attempting to normalize them can make them blow up exponentially. Assuming I can even parse the regex itself, which I would have to write a parser for by hand.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to compare two strings for equivalence regardless of their normalization form, ICU has [`unorm_compare()`](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu-docs/apidoc/released/icu4c/unorm2_8h.html#aee41897bd6c4ff7dc7a8db6d37efdcbd). Example:

```cpp
// g++ -Wall -Wextra -O $(icu-config --cppflags --cxxflags --ldflags --ldflags-icuio) -o demo demo.cpp
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <unicode/unorm2.h>
#include <unicode/unistr.h>
#include <unicode/ustream.h>

int main(void) {
  UErrorCode err = U_ZERO_ERROR;
  icu::UnicodeString a{u"a\u0065\u0301b"}, b{u"a\u00E9b"};

  int res = unorm_compare(a.getBuffer(), a.length(),
                          b.getBuffer(), b.length(),
                          U_COMPARE_IGNORE_CASE, &err);
  if (U_FAILURE(err)) {
    std::cerr << "unorm_compare() error: " << u_errorName(err) << '\n';
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  if (res == 0) {
    std::cout << a << " and " << b << " are equivalent.\n";
  } else {
    std::cout << a << " and " << b << " differ.\n";
  }
}
```

when compiled and run, prints out

```
aéb and aéb are equivalent.
```

Comment: I was asking about regular expressions. This isn't a regular expression matcher...